# sed removing line breaks tail

Tags: linux, sed, tail

In my Python script I needed a fast/efficient way to set a max filesize on a file I'm constantly writing to. Rather than bring the whole thing into py's RAM, I ran this shell command:

`sed -i '1d' file.csv`

I monitor the filesize periodically and run the command as needed. Problem is that now if I `tail -f file.csv`, tail stops tailing the file as soon as sed removes a line from it. Any solution?

Comment: How about `tail -F`?

Comment: Do you find any of the suggestions you received helpful? Please provide an update as to how you are faring.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is `sed` creates a new file. This is shown by the extract below:

```
$ strace -fe trace=file,read,write,close sed -i '1d'  /tmp/x.csv 
....
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/x.csv", O_RDONLY) = 3
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/sed1nFxY1", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
write(5, NULL, 0)                       = 0
read(3, "1,1,1,1\n2,2,2,2\n3,3,3,3\n", 4096) = 24
write(4, "2,2,2,2\n", 8)                = 8
write(4, "3,3,3,3\n", 8)                = 8
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
rename("/tmp/sed1nFxY1", "/tmp/x.csv")  = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
```

There isn't, as far as I know, an easy way to truncate the start of a file.

I'd suggest getting your python application to listen on a unix/tcp socket, and once accepted put that stream into the [logging framework](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) and then use `nc ... | tail` to watch output.

Comment: This is a good explanation, but not really a quick solution...

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) suggests the obvious `tail -F`, but I personally mostly use `less` nowadays:

```
less --follow-name +F file.csv
```

There being no shorthand alternative to `--follow-name`, I have to use an alias:

```
alias less='less --follow-name -XFR'
```